# Laravel cannot set id on eloquent creating event

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I'm trying to give my modal a custom id (no auto increment). So I've overwrite the `boot` method of my modal. The creating event is used like this:

```
public static function boot()
{
    static::creating(function ($modal) {
        $modal->id = $myID;
        return true;
    });
}
```

Now when I try to revert the id after saving an entry the id of the new entry is alwas `0`.

```
$modal = new Modal;
$modal->myValue = $myValue;
$modal->save();

dd($modal->id) // This will returns always 0
```

The strange thing is that the record is successful written to the database with the right id.

What is wrong with my code?

**Edit:**
It's not returning `null`. It's returning `0`

Comment: Try this : $modal->getKey();

Comment: It's also `null`.

Comment: Is your id fillable?

Comment: Yes, it's in the `$fillable` array

Comment: You need to add this: 
public $incrementing = false;

Comment: Please post your idea as answer. So you can earn your reputation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable auto increment with setting property `$incrementing` to false in your model.

```
public $incrementing = false
```